# SQLLite different behaviour in different Android SDK

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, behavior

take a look at the following query:

Query:

```
SELECT
  [10_Departments].[DepID] AS DepID,
  [70_Types].[TypeName] AS TypeName,
  [10_Departments].[DepName] AS DepName,
  [10_Departments].[Description] AS Description,
  [10_Departments].[HTML] AS HTML,
  [70_Pictures].[PictureFilename] AS PictureFilename,
  [40_AvailableDeps].[DepID] AS AvailDepID
FROM (([70_Types]
INNER JOIN (([80_Deps_Pictures]
INNER JOIN [10_Departments]
  ON [80_Deps_Pictures].[DepID] = [10_Departments].[DepID])
INNER JOIN [70_Pictures]
  ON [80_Deps_Pictures].[PicID] = [70_Pictures].[PicID])
  ON [70_Types].[TypeID] = [10_Departments].[Type])
LEFT JOIN [40_AvailableDeps]
  ON [10_Departments].[DepID] = [40_AvailableDeps].[DepID])
WHERE [10_Departments].[Type] = 2
ORDER BY [10_Departments].[DepID]
```

The previous query with the same database installed both in Android 4.2.2 and Android 7.0 in the second works perfect but in the first it reports the error that the `[10_Departments].[DepID]` column was not found. I was selecting before `[10_Departments].*` and it was reporting that the table `[10_Departments]` was not found. The fact is that in both SDK cases it is there as it is the same database...

Any insights anyone?

Thanks

Edit - Both in DB Browser for SQLLite and SQLite Expert Personal 5 the query executes against the database with no problem.

Edit#2 - The application connects to the database as in another activity I read data from it with no problem (plain query - no join query - not the same table).

Edit#3 - I tried to read the records from the table with a plain query (f.e. "SELECT * FROM [10_Departments]") and it executes with no problem (the table is there).

Comment: What if you "SELECT [DepID] FROM [10_Departments]" ?

Comment: Hi nasch. Thanks for answering. When I select the query you mentioned it returns the [DepID] with no problem. I believe it has something to do with the inner join and the version of the SDK.

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure then.  I don't see any issues with the query.  I would build up the query a little bit at a time and see where it starts failing.  Maybe that will at least give you something more specific to investigate.

Comment: I have found a solution. The joins have to be rearranged and remove the parentheses. Here are the new joins: "    FROM [80_Deps_Pictures] INNER JOIN [10_Departments] ON [80_Deps_Pictures].[DepID] = [10_Departments].[DepID]
         INNER JOIN [70_Pictures] ON [80_Deps_Pictures].[PicID] = [70_Pictures].[PicID]
         INNER JOIN [70_Types] ON [70_Types].[TypeID] = [10_Departments].[Type]
         LEFT JOIN [40_AvailableDeps] ON [10_Departments].[DepID] = [40_AvailableDeps].[DepID]"

Answer (score 0):

This is a typical error in queries with multiple joins generated with the MS Access query builder (for some strange reason, it puts parentheses around joins, which restricts the visibility of other table's columns in some SQLite versions).

Just remove all parentheses, and do the joins one by one. If you have outer joins, you have to ensure that later joins don't remove rows with NULL values, typically by writing them last.

Please note that when joining on two columns with the same name, using USING is simpler:

```
FROM [80_Deps_Pictures]
JOIN [10_Departments] USING (DepID)
JOIN [70_Pictures] USING (PicID)
JOIN [70_Types] ON [70_Types].[TypeID] = [10_Departments].[Type]
LEFT JOIN [40_AvailableDeps] USING (DepID)
```